# Set precision an element in Matlab matrix

Tags: matlab, precision

I want to set precision for all element of a matrix. Below is what I did:

```
>>A

A =

         0    1.0000         0         0         0         0
 -137.0830         0         0         0         0         0
         0         0         0    1.0000         0         0
  365.5546         0         0         0         0         0
         0         0         0         0         0    1.0000
  365.5546         0         0         0         0         0

>> vpa(A,2)

ans =

[      0, 1.0, 0,   0, 0,   0]
[ -144.0,   0, 0,   0, 0,   0]
[      0,   0, 0, 1.0, 0,   0]
[  377.0,   0, 0,   0, 0,   0]
[      0,   0, 0,   0, 0, 1.0]
[  377.0,   0, 0,   0, 0,   0]
```

The result is not my desire, it should be:
-137.08, 365.55, 365.55 in the first column.
Please help to suggest me how to get it.
Thank you so much!

Comment: `137.08` has *five* significant digits and you are only requesting 2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using `vpa` correctly. From the [docs](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html):

> vpa(x,d) uses at least d significant digits

Nota that it says *at least*. That is why you still get 377 when you only asked for 2 significant digits.

It seems that you don't know what significant digits are. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures):

> The significant figures of a number are digits that carry meaning
>   contributing to its measurement resolution. This includes all digits
>   except:
>
> - All leading zeros;
> - Trailing zeros when they are merely placeholders to indicate the scale of the number (exact rules are explained at identifying
>     significant figures); and
> - Spurious digits introduced, for example, by calculations carried out to greater precision than that of the original data, or measurements
>     reported to a greater precision than the equipment supports.

So you want this

```
>> vpa(365.5546, 5)
ans =
365.55
```

Now, to be consistent, you need to find out what is the maximum of your matrix and [compute the desired number of significant digits](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/10795-counting-the-number-of-digits) from there.

```
max_number = floor(log10(max(abs(A(:))+1)) + 1);
decimals = 2;
vpa(A, max_number + decimals)
```

Here, `max_number` is the maximum number of *integer* digits that your matrix has, and `decimals` is the number of decimal places that you want to have.

Comment: @greenworld I fixed an error `max_number`, in case you are using that line. I also added a brief clarification on that part of the code.

Answer (score 1):

The [second input](https://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/vpa.html#inputarg_d) to `vpa` is the [number of significant digits](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures) which is *not* the same as the number of values after the radix point. The number `-137.08` actually has *five* signficant digits so you'll want to use a second input of `5`

```
vpa(A, 5)

% [       0, 1.0, 0,   0, 0,   0]
% [ -137.08,   0, 0,   0, 0,   0]
% [       0,   0, 0, 1.0, 0,   0]
% [  365.55,   0, 0,   0, 0,   0]
% [       0,   0, 0,   0, 0, 1.0]
% [  365.55,   0, 0,   0, 0,   0]
```

Answer (score -1):

`vpa(x,d)` : 
`d` is significant digits, not decimal places.

```
pvalue = vpa(-137.0830);
twopvalue = vpa(-137.0830,2);

% pvalue = -137.08299999999999840838427189738
% twopvalue = -144.0
```

If you want to get -137.08, 365.55, 365.55 in the first column. You can use `roundn(A,-2)`

```
roundn(A,-2)

ans =

         0    1.0000         0         0         0         0
 -137.0800         0         0         0         0         0
         0         0         0    1.0000         0         0
  365.5500         0         0         0         0         0
         0         0         0         0         0    1.0000
  365.5500         0         0         0         0         0
```

Comment: If you know the difference between significant digits and decimal places, how come do you advise him to use `round`? See the difference between `round(0.001, 2)` and  `vpa(0.001, 2)`.

Comment: I'm sorry that I was a little insensitive. Thanks for your valuable comments.